# Java app running on Amazon EC2 - redirect http to https

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2

I have recently started using Amazon AWS for hosting my website. I have self signed ssl certificate installed for website and it's working fine. I also see correct Virtual Hosts created for this single website running on on this Amazon EC2 server. I want to redirect all the http traffic to https and for that I added:
Redirect permanent / https://mywebsite.com/ , but my website is still not getting redirected to https. Is there anything else I need to do make this work?
FYI - I am not using Load Balance and not planning to use one right now.

Comment: Where did you add the redirect? Can you add to your post the VirtualHost sections of your Apache configuration file?

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mywebsite.com
  ServerAlias root
  DocumentRoot /srv/www/root/current/

  <Directory /srv/www/root/current/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </Directory>

  RewriteEngine On
  Include /etc/httpd/sites-available/root.conf.d/rewrite*
  RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/root-rewrite.log
  RewriteLogLevel 0


  Include /etc/httpd/sites-available/root.conf.d/local*

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
Redirect permanent / https://mywebsite.com/
</VirtualHost>

Comment: <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName mywebsite.com
  ServerAlias root
  DocumentRoot /srv/www/root/current/

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mywebsite.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mywebsite.key
  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

  RewriteEngine On
  Include /etc/httpd/sites-available/root.conf.d/rewrite-ssl*
  RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/root-rewrite.log
  RewriteLogLevel 0

 ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>

Comment: website is not allowing me to post bigger comments. Divided my VH information in 2 messages. Please look at last line of first post to see redirect permanent I am doing. Thanks

Comment: @user3616677 you should have edited that into your question instead of putting it in comments...

Comment: It's not allowing with so many urls as I am a new user and don't have enough reputation points

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect should include the https protocol part. Try this:

```
Redirect permanent / https://mywebsite.com
```

Comment: Victor, I have added that to vh:80. Please see my first comment. For some reason https is stripped from comment.

Comment: Have you restarted your apache server?

Comment: I see that you don't have / at the end if URL. Does that make difference.

Comment: No, it should work with that final slash. Is your apache error log logging anything?

Comment: Victor didn't find anything there. But this isse is resolved now. I didn't had rewrite rule. Only question now I have is do you need to put both rewrite and redirect rule or just one should be sufficient. I am going to try this but wanted find out which is the better way. Thanks

Comment: For what you are trying to achieve, the redirect rule is enough